# button con método no se puede asignar un evento

Tags: botón

Estimados tengo este button que tiene ya un método asignado y lo que hace es abrir y cerrar un dialogo. a este button le he asignado un evento de click on.click usando las clases que ya tiene asignadas para poder hacer un show o hide a otro objeto o div pero el evento que asigno no funciona o mi evento no es alcanzable, alguna idea que podría probar espero se entienda dejo la imagen del botón.

[image: botón con método]

```js
$('.close').on("click", function() {
            $('#overlay').hide();
        });
```

Gracias

Hola a ver voy a ampliar mi pregunta este es la función de inicialización

```js
  function initSidebar() {
        if (miniCart.data('mageSidebar')) {
            miniCart.sidebar('update');
        }

        if (!$('[data-role=product-item]').length) {
            return false;
        }
        miniCart.trigger('contentUpdated');

        if (sidebarInitialized) {
            return false;
        }
        sidebarInitialized = true;
        miniCart.sidebar({
            'targetElement': 'div.block.block-minicart',
            'url': {
                'checkout': window.checkout.checkoutUrl,
                'update': window.checkout.updateItemQtyUrl,
                'remove': window.checkout.removeItemUrl,
                'loginUrl': window.checkout.customerLoginUrl,
                'isRedirectRequired': window.checkout.isRedirectRequired
            },
            'button': {
                'checkout': '#top-cart-btn-checkout',
                'remove': '#mini-cart a.action.delete',
                'close': '#btn-minicart-close',
            },
        });
    }
    
   // a esta funcion le creen este metodo para cerrar el dialogo
    
     closeSidebar: function() {
            var minicart = $('[data-block="minicart"]');
            minicart.on('click', '[data-action="close"]', function(event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                minicart.find('[data-role="dropdownDialog"]').dropdownDialog('close');
            });

            return true;
        }
        
   //estoy creando esta función para cerrar este div o ocultar pero no funciona 
   
   jQuery(function($) {
  jQuery(document).on('click', ".close", function(e){
           $('#overlay').hide();
        });
});
```

Comment: ¿Cómo/Dónde se ejecuta tu código JS? Puede que el botón se cree después de intentar asociar el evento. ¿Has probado a usar eventos delegados? Algo como `$("body").on("click", ".close", function() { ... })`. Te recomiendo que edites la pregunta para añadir esa información, además sería bueno que incluyeras un [mcve] para que podamos ver el problema, que pongas el código como texto (las imágenes no se indexan bien) y que etiquetes mejor la pregunta ("botón" no dice nada, sería mejor indicar JavaScript o jQuery).

Comment: La verdad no se entiende nada en tu pregunta